# Empty() publisher does not send completion

Tags: swift, combine

In this code I am expecting the `Empty()` publisher to send completion to the `.sink` subscriber, but no completion is sent.

```
func testEmpty () {
    let x = XCTestExpectation()

    let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

    emptyOrSubjectPublisher(subject).sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        dump(completion)
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        dump(value)
    }).store(in: &cancellables)

    subject.send(0)

    wait(for: [x], timeout: 10.0)
}

func emptyOrSubjectPublisher (_ subject: PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>) -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
    subject
        .flatMap { (i: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> in
            if i == 1 {
                return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
            } else {
                return Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Why does the `emptyOrSubjectPublisher` not receive the completion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Empty completes, but the overall pipeline does not, because the initial Subject has not completed. The inner pipeline in which the Empty is produced (the `flatMap`) has "swallowed" the completion. This is the expected behavior.

You can see this more easily by simply producing a Just in the `flatMap`, e.g. `Just(100)`:

```
    subject
    .flatMap {_ in Just(100) }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print(completion)
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        print(value)
    }).store(in: &cancellables)
    subject.send(1)
```

You know and I know that a Just emits once and completes. But although the *value* of the Just arrives down the pipeline, there is no completion.

And you can readily see why it works this way. It would be very wrong if we had a potential sequence of values from our publisher but some intermediate publisher, produced in a `flatMap`, had the power to complete the whole pipeline and end it prematurely.

(And see my https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsflatmap.html where I make the same point.)

If the goal is to send a completion down the pipeline, it's the `subject` that needs to complete. For example, you could say

```
func emptyOrSubjectPublisher (_ subject: PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>) -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
    subject
        .flatMap { (i: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> in
            if i == 1 {
                return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
            } else {
                subject.send(completion: .finished) // <--
                return Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

[Note, however, that your whole `emptyOrSubjectPublisher` is peculiar; it is unclear what purpose it is intended to serve. Returning `subject` when `i` is `1` is kind of pointless too, because `subject` has already published the `1` by the time we get here, and isn't going to publish anything more right now. Thus, if you send `1` at the start, you won't receive `1` as a value, because your `flatMap` has swallowed it and has produced a publisher that isn't going to publish.]

Comment: Okay, makes more sense now - thank you. And thanks also for the reading material! `emptyOrSubjectPublisher` was a hastily-concocted test construct.

Comment: No problem, glad to see the interest in the Combine framework. Your question was a good one!

Comment: Also a simpler way to remember how `flatMap` behaves is that it reflects all value events and failures to the parent `Publisher` but not completed events.

Comment: @SlashDevSlashGnoll As I said, see https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsflatmap.html